# provisioning profile nightmare

Tags: xcode, ipad, provisioning

Just had an end client experience a nightmare that is mysterious.
He began the process of adding an ad hoc prototype of app.
He is saying that when he added the mobile Team Provisioning Profile that is associated with the app and the device synched, all of his apps got wiped.

I witnessed a designer go through the same process without any of this nightmare.

Any ideas what might have happened and more importantly how to avoid this from happening again?

I am praying that iTunes is smart enough to see he already purchased his apps and will just reinstall without making him pay for it again.

Comment: At least, he need not pay again.

Answer (score 0):

when syncing the device select the device->go to the apps tab in itunes->select the checkbox to sync the apps and then select only the app you want to install and then sync

Comment: Thanks, Govind. I figured this was a syncing issue and not really anything with installing the profile. I'm guessing one other thing to warn the client is to make sure the device is set to synch manually rather than automatic when he plugs it in.